# Google Analytics tracking events within php

Tags: php, google-analytics

I want to track events via google analytics for items loading on the page. Basically if a banner image shows on a page I want to track the impression via an event using google analytics. So for example:

```
pageTracker._trackEvent('BannerImages','Impression','Banner Ad Name Here');
```

Where would I put this? Here is the php code:

```
$query = $dbconn->query("SELECT * FROM banner_images LIMIT 5");

foreach($query AS $banner_result)
{

echo '<div>' .$banner_result->location .'</div>';

}
```

Would I echo out the pageTracker code after each value is echoed out for $banner_result->location like so?

```
echo '<div>' .$banner_result->location .'<div>' ."\n" .'<script>pageTracker._trackEvent('BannerImages','Impression','Banner Ad Name Here');</script>';
```

The google tracking code is in the footer.

**EDIT**

Looks like I have to add it after the tracking code initializes.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add it after the tracking code initializes if you use the asynchronous code: https://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would collect all pageTracker items in an array

```
foreach($query AS $banner_result){
    echo '<div>' .$banner_result->location .'</div>';
    $googleAnalytics[] = "pageTracker._trackEvent('BannerImages','Impression','".$banner_result->yourBannerName."');";
}
```

And add them after you included the async Google Analytics code:

```
echo '<script>'.implode("\n",$googleAnalytics).'</script>';
```